# DataGridRow animation WPF gives error for CellsPanelHorizontalOffset

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, datagrid

I have an animation for my DataGridRow that is when a new row is added, it slides it in from left to the view. everything works fine but in the binding errors, I see an error.
The animation code is added to LoadingRow event:

```
 var sb = new Storyboard();
 var slideAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation()
 {
     From = new Thickness(-dgData.ActualWidth, 0, dgData.ActualWidth, 0),
     To = new Thickness(0),
     Duration = new System.Windows.Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
 };
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideAnimation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));
 sb.Children.Add(slideAnimation);
 sb.Begin(e.Row);
```

the error is:

```
 DataGridControl, Name='dgData' CellsPanelHorizontalOffset  Button.Width Double Value '-58.32884999999999' (type Double) cannot be assigned to property Button.Width (type Double).
```

there are a bunch of errors like this every time a new row is added. how to solve the issue?

Comment: It looks like, the binding error's are happening because of negative numbers. When I changed the `ThicknessAnimation.From` to be always positive. The binding errors dissapeared.

Comment: @Jan3Sobieski yeah you are right but i want slide animation on Row :)

Answer (score 1):

After a little digging, I found out why the binding error is popping up.
The internals of `DataGridCellsPanel` which is a template for `DataGrid.ItemsPanel`. Binds and Calculates the Width for Button (CellsPanelHorizontalOffset).

You can find the source code for that in file DataGridCellsPanel.cs at line 1983.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGridCellsPanel.cs

If the Grid.Row size is incorrect, the `DataGridCellsPanel` will calculate the Width with negative value. Which leads to Binding Error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : 
Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property. Double:'-92.3575' 
BindingExpression:Path=CellsPanelHorizontalOffset; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='dgData');
target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')
```

That's one of thousands internal bugs in WPF, I would suggest to use a different method, then going into negatives for Row. For example you can use `Scale.X`

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="s_Slide">
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleX"/>                    
    </Storyboard>
                
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource s_Slide}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution and it is fine. but actually, it is not exactly what I want. it shows the row scaling along x but I am looking for the sliding animation. do you think it is possible to achieve it without errors?

Comment: isn't there any hack to the problem so when the negative value is about to be set we set it manually to 0 to prevent error. I mean to subscribe to some event for doing this?